# Chaining promise to create ec2 instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, promise

I want to rewrite a script in a promise way which previously using callback to create ec2 instance. My logic is first trying to describe the securityGroups. If not exist,  create one, otherwise proceed to describe the keyPairs. If keypairs not exist, create one and write the privatekey to file, otherwise proceed to create instance.

Somehow I manage to do so as below, but I'm not satisfied with the flatness of the code. There're still lots of indentation. Moreover, I found that my logic force me to nest chain promise in catch block, which isn't the way people usually do in those tutorial, thus made me doubting the way and initial purpose of using promise.

```
var describeSecurityGroupsInstance = ec2.describeSecurityGroups(securityGroups).promise()
//1st level chain
describeSecurityGroupsInstance.then(function(data){
    console.log("SecurityGroups Already Exist")
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Unable to describe SecurityGroup", err)
    var createSecurityGroupInstance = ec2.createSecurityGroup(securityGroup).promise()
    //2nd level chain
    createSecurityGroupInstance.then(function(data){
        console.log("SecurityGroup test created") 
        var describeKeyPairsInstance = ec2.describeKeyPairs(keyPairs).promise()
        return describeKeyPairsInstance
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log("KeyPair Already Exist, make sure you have private key locally to proceed")
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("Unable to describe KeyPairs", err)
        var createKeyPairInstance = ec2.createKeyPair(keyPair).promise()
        //3rd level chain
        createKeyPairInstance.then(function(data){
            console.log("KeyPair test created")
            const writeFileInstance = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)
            privateKey=data.KeyMaterial
            return writeFileInstance('test.pem',privateKey)
        }).then(function(data){
            console.log("keypair content write to file")
            var instancePromise = ec2.runInstances(instanceParams).promise()
            return instancePromise
        }).then(function(data){
            console.log("instance just created")
            console.log(data)
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("Unable to create KeyPair or unable to write to file or create instance", err, err.stack)
        })
    })
})
```

So right now, I have 3 level of promise chain.

My first question is am I able to put `describeKeyPairsInstance` promise into top level chain right after catch block of `describeSecurityGroupsInstance`, since logically after checking with securityGroup, we should check KeyPairs or reversely.(IMO the order between these two steps shouldn't matter, correct me if I'm wrong). Basically I could endure nested chain for tackling securityGroups' non existence, as it is a have-to, but not the `describeKeyPairsInstance` part. If this goal could be achieved, I think `writeFileInstance` could be append to top level chain as well, then problem is solved. So the problem become how to return promise from 2nd level chain to top level chain. Right now although I think it's not feasible, but I really appreciate if there is a solution.

My second question is the logic of creating ec2 instance itself. Should I simply get rid of `describeSecurityGroups/KeyPairs` these two promise, instead check the existence based on `createSecurityGroup/KeyPair` promise's rejection? If so, then I could just chain promise no matter securityGroup and keyPair exist or not. But idempotently speaking, shouldn't we check the existence first?

My third question is about general usage of promise. Is it bad practice to nest promise chain in catch block? If so, what is the alternative way with and without promise?

Answer any of the questions would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the fact that you put `function(whatever)` indented on a new line in the .then and .error is indenting the code more than it needs - other than that, I can't immediately see a different way to write that code, (other than refactoring some of the code to functions, or perhaps using async/await)

Comment: @JaromandaX get rid of the unnecessary indentation does make it look better. But major problem is still there

Comment: what major problem? there isn't a major problem if the code works as intended

Comment: @OscarZhang, potential issue with code as written - failure of `ec2.createSecurityGroup()` will be caught by the "Unable to describe KeyPairs" handler. Maybe intentional, maybe not. Either way, it would be a good idea to catch or catch/rethrow that error to demonstrate that you have condidered it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript ES7 introduced [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if you aren't familiar with it, which is there to solve the exact issue you're describing. It's essentially syntactic sugar around what you already have, but it definitely looks nicer instead of doing `.then` and chaining them together.

Comment: you know what would make this a better answer? If you showed how async/await could help with the code in the question, because, I don't think it would help anywhere near as much as you think

Answer (score 1):

BY "inverting" the success/fail logic of `ec2.describeSecurityGroups` and  `ec2.describeKeyPairs` you can "flatten" this code

```
const writeFileInstance = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const describeSecurityGroupsInstance () => ec2.describeSecurityGroups(securityGroups).promise()
    .then(() => { throw 'SecurityGroups Already Exist'}, err => err);
const describeKeyPairsInstance = () => ec2.describeKeyPairs(keyPairs).promise()
    .then(() => { throw 'KeyPair Already Exist, make sure you have private key locally to proceed'}, err => err);

describeSecurityGroupsInstance()
.then(res => {
    console.log("Unable to describe SecurityGroup", res);
    return ec2.createSecurityGroup(securityGroup).promise();
})
.then(describeKeyPairsInstance)
.then(res => {
    console.log("Unable to describe KeyPairs", res);
    return ec2.createKeyPair(keyPair).promise();
})
.then(data => {
    console.log("KeyPair test created");
    privateKey = data.KeyMaterial;
    return writeFileInstance('test.pem',privateKey);
})
.then(data => {
    console.log("keypair content write to file")
    return ec2.runInstances(instanceParams).promise();
})
.then(data => {
    console.log("instance just created");
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(err => {
    if (typeof err === 'string') {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
});
```

using async/await (along with the inverted logic) the code looks even cleaner

```
const writeFileInstance = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const describeSecurityGroupsInstance () => ec2.describeSecurityGroups(securityGroups).promise()
    .then(() => { throw 'SecurityGroups Already Exist'}, err => err);
const describeKeyPairsInstance = () => ec2.describeKeyPairs(keyPairs).promise()
    .then(() => { throw 'KeyPair Already Exist, make sure you have private key locally to proceed'}, err => err);

try {
    const sec = await describeSecurityGroupsInstance();
    console.log("Unable to describe SecurityGroup", sec);
    await ec2.createSecurityGroup(securityGroup).promise();
    const kpi = await describeKeyPairsInstance();
    console.log("Unable to describe KeyPairs", kpi);
    const kp = await ec2.createKeyPair(keyPair).promise();
    console.log("KeyPair test created");
    privateKey = kp.KeyMaterial;
    await writeFileInstance('test.pem',privateKey);
    console.log("keypair content write to file");
    const data = await ec2.runInstances(instanceParams).promise();
    console.log("instance just created");
    console.log(data);
} catch(err) {
    if (typeof err === 'string') {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
});
```